# Laravel Eloquent : Get the value of related table instead of foriegn key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using eloquent query

```
$apv = $node->products()->with('brand','skus.defaultImage')->get();
```

to get all products and its variation and other related models. this is the collection I get:

[image]

In places like `supplier_id` in the outer array
and `option_id` in the `outerarray>skus>values` array I need to get corresponding values from (such as '`sipplier_name`') table columns instead of just a foreign key.

Comment: Do you have a supplier relation on your `product` model? If so, add it to the `with` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all.I added join statement in Model

```
class Variant extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];


    public function optval()
    {
        $intance = $this->hasMany(OptionValue::class);
         $intance->join('options', 'option_value.option_id', '=', 'options.id')            
            ->get(['option_label','value']);
     return $intance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might can use **appends**

```
class Product extends Model
{
     ....
     ....

     protected $appends = ['supplier_name'];

     public function supplier()
     {
          return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class);
     }

     public function getSupplierNameAttribute()
     {
           return $this->supplier()->supplier_name;
     }
}
```

//example use

```
$product = Product::first();
$product->supplier_name;
```

Comment: `public class` ? Is it mistake?

Comment: oh.. yeah.. its a mistake.. @SergeyShuryakov tq

Answer (score 0):

```
class Product extends Model
{
     ....
     ....


     public class supplier()
     {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\Supplier','supplier_id');
     }

}
```

now get product with supplier

```
$product = Product::where('id',$product_id)->with('supplier')->first();
echo $supplier_name= $product->supplier['supplier_name'];
```